# Fourier coefficients of fluid velocity in Cosmology

Tags: cosmology, fourier-transform

I start with the following equation, that can be obtained by taking the curl of the continuity equation, and in which $\omega=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{v}$ is the curl of the velocity field of the cosmological fluid $\vec{v}$:

$$\vec{\omega'}+\mathcal{H}\vec{\omega}+\vec{\nabla}\times(\vec{v}\times\vec{\omega})=0$$

The set of notes that I am reading states that, *in the case of vanishing curl, we have:*

$$\vec{v}(\vec{k})=i\dfrac{\vec{k}}{k^2}\theta(\vec{k})$$

where $\theta=\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{v}$. I would like to be able to understand where this comes from, but I don't know where to start or what to do. It looks suspiciously similar to something I read in a paper recently, where they stated that *the Fourier coefficient of $\vec{u}(\vec{x})$* (which seems to be their way of denoting the velocity field $\vec{v}$) *is given by:*

$$\dfrac{i}{k^2}\big[-\theta(\vec{k})\vec{k}+\vec{k}\times\omega(\vec{k})\big]$$

I suspect that the curl refers to $\omega$, and since in the paper they wrote the Helmholtz decomposition of $v$ as $\vec{u}(\vec{x})=-\vec{\nabla}A+\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}$, if the curl vanishes we would be left with the first term of this decomposition, which seems to somehow produce the first term of the Fourier coefficient of $\vec{v}$.

Is someone able to clarify this? This intuition that I am describing is not enough for me to complete the calculations. I am aware that $\theta=\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{v}$ implies $\theta(\vec{k})=i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{v}(\vec{k})$ since their Fourier convention causes the nabla operator to be represented in Fourier space as $i\vec{k}$, but I don't know how to obtain the desired result.

Thank you very much in advance!